# Copying only Chord Symbols in Finale

Tags: chords, software, finale

I have been transcribing some songs in Finale and tried to copy chord symbols from one instrument's part to another. However the whole measure is copied and pasted so it erases everything in the desired measure and replaces it with the copied measure. Is there a way I can only copy the chord symbols in Finale?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a filter.

First **Edit Filter** in the **Edit** menu to apply copy paste only to **Markings** > **Chords & Fretboards**.

Then set the menu **Edit** > **Use Filter**.

Finally copy and paste and those actions will only apply to whatever is selected in the filter.